# Setting up Jenkins and git-server on same server

Tags: jenkins, deployment, git, continuous-deployment

I want to setup a Jenkins and git on the same server.

What I am trying to do:

I want Jenkins to be able deploy a folder to another server which runs IIS server (which is running `.net`).
I don't have code as I bought the product the client provides me with . It's just a publish folder or the executable files which I directly put on the server .I will be using `git` for version controlling.

> I want jenkins to periodically check the git repository and when it finds any changes, it deploys it over to my remote server which is running IIS and rename the old folder on git with date wise.

How should I go about implementing this?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Instead of pulling for changes why don't you use git hooks (https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks) to do your task on git changes?

Answer (score 3):

For me I use `jenkins` in docker with git plugin.

The Git plugin will give you the ability to check the Git server every specific period of time or you can use git hook from github or bitbucket to trigger the task when ever any change happened to the repo or the branch.

For deployment, most of time I use shell build step to execute some shell command on remote node.